# How to use overlay dialog from jQuery for feedback form

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog (on click) for feedback. I've tried simple things first.
[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3m5D/)

```
$("#feed_win").dialog({
    autoOpen:false;
});


$("#feedback").click( function() {
    $( "#feed_win" ).dialog( "open" ); 
});
```

But every time on load the dialog contains are shown before the button click event. Any help will be useful.

So, now i tried this.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#feedback").button().click(function() {
          $("#feed_win").dialog("open");
        });

        $("#feed_win").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 400
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="feedback">Delete profile</button>

          <div id="feed_win">
            <h2>This is feedback form</h2>
            <p>You can add your feedback here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

But the dialog div is displayed on page load. why? It should be displayed after clicking button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI script in the head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FRJg4/)

Everything else you wrote is good, just add that line

Comment: thanks for help. How can i add overlay there? and how to that close appears? can we add CSS to it?

Comment: jQuery user interface adds close button, it's part of jQuery UI, you can change CSS, inspect code and see classes, but maybe it's better to use jQuery Theme Roller, you can find it at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ website. 
Also I recommend you to check this site: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal
you can find everything about jQuery dialogs, modal windows, and it's whole documentation (you can change button text, make div resizable, change title...). You need to include jQuery UI stylesheet to change CSS of buttons and windows.
I hope it helps, I will help more tomorrow if needed